# Ember.js : How to set context of an action helper?

Tags: ember.js

I added the example application.
http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/amG56/

Js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedBook: null
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({

  actions: {
    selectBook: function(book) {
      this.get('controller').set("selectedBook", book);
    },

    cancel: function(book) {
      alert(book);
    }
  }
});

App.Book = Em.Object.extend({
  name: null
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#each book in books}}
    <a {{action "selectBook" book target="view"}} href="#">select {{book.name}}</a><br />
  {{/each}}
  <hr />
  Selected Book: {{selectedBook.name}}
  <br />
  <a {{action "cancel" selectedBook target="view"}} href="#">cancel selected book</a>
</script>
```

​

Select one of the books. You will see that name of the book will be displayed. But the "cancel selected book" link does not work.

I think the problem is context of the action helper does not change when a book is selected.

How do I implement an action helper which has a changing context? Or is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The answer is in the guides
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters**

And the context is lazily evaluated, so the problem does not occur anymore

**DEPRECATED ANSWER BELOW**

The problem here is that the action helper is interpreted with the selectedBook context. But at this time, selectedBook is null. So when clicking on the link, even if you previously select a book, it's too late, for the registered action, the context is still null.
As a workaround, you can enclose this with a {{with}} block.

```
{{#with selectedBook}} 
  Selected Book: {{name}}
  <br />
  <a {{action cancel this target="view"}} href="#">cancel selected   book</a>
{{/with}}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/x82dr/17/

BTW, you can see the code of the ApplicationView, where I access the application controller, using the controller property. With Ember.js convention, the controller is injected to the view when the application initialize

UPDATE: The use of the {{with}} helper seems to be not mandatory now, see: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1150

Comment: Thanks for the usage of the "controller", I got it. But this does not work either because with your code, selectedBook is not null but the first book selected. When I select a different book, action helper still has the first book as context.

Comment: Hm, see my edited answer, I use an other workaround, the {{/with}} helper. It works better.Though I think there should definitely be an improvement in the action helper. There is an open issue about it: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1515

Comment: Thanks, "with" helper seems to solve this problem. But it does not feel right. I hope my templates does not fill with "with" helpers :). I guess I will use your solution until this issue resolved. Watching the issue on github. Thanks again. I was struggling for a few days.

Comment: The other workaround if you don't want to use {{with}} helper, is to retrieve the context from the controller when the event is send. some thing like cancel: function(event) {
        this.get('controller.selectedBook') ...
    }

Comment: Yes, I considered that too. I don't want to be a jerk but that does not feel right either. Because I have to pass a context to action helper but I won't use it. It is misleading.

Comment: I think you're right, as I say, these are work arounds, clearly not the best solutions. Though, passing a context to action helper is not mandatory

Comment: @İ.EmreKutlu Hi, see my update, I think you can now avoid the use of {{with}}